# Using an array PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use an array to determine whether or not an album needs to be displayed, as opposed to a single image. Here is, logically, how I am trying to do it:

1) Select all of the single images (rows) from the table moments (they are called moments)

2) if the image does not have a value set in the alb_id column then display it normally

3) if the image has an alb_id value see if it has been stored in the array to keep track of the alb_id's.

4) if it is in the array skip that row, or else display an album and add that alb_id from the image to the array so that any future images with that alb_id will not be displayed.

Here is what I am trying. Although it doesn't seem right. Nor does it work.

```
    $connect= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'thesocialnetwork')
        or die('error connecting');
    $query= "SELECT * FROM moments WHERE user_id= '".$user_id."' ORDER BY     
            order_date DESC";
    $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $list= array($album);
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (!empty($row[alb_id'])) {    
                    if (!in_array($row['alb_id'], $list)) {
           $album.= $row['alb_id'];
                       display a new album;
                    }
                    else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    just display the single image;
                }
```

So, I guess my question is, is my logic correct? Also, what is best way to create a new array, test against that array, and also add to that array? I mean, in regards to what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Try this `$album = array()` instead of `$list= array($album);` & `$album[] = $row['alb_id'];` instead of `$album.= $row['alb_id'];`

Comment: What are you getting ? What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for membership in an array, it's best to use an associative array, and use the things you're checking as keys. So the logic should be:

```
$list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $alb = $row['alb_id'];
  if (!empty($alb)) {
    if (!isset($list[$alb]) {
      $list[$alb] = true;
      // display a new album
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  } else {
    // display the single image
  }
}
```